# Subscript out of range error 9

Tags: vba, excel, error-handling

I keep getting that error when trying to do this:

```
Dim MaxFileSize As Long    
...
MaxFileSize = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Worksheets("'system32-he'").Range("B2:B24"))
```

I've tried googling it but nothing useful came up.

Comment: Check the spelling of the worksheet, are you sure there should be a single quote in there?

Comment: @vba4all no actually I wasnt. I guess it works now, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reference see [MSDN Subscript out of range error 9](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264519(v=vs.60).aspx)

In your case the Worksheets Collection can't return the correct sheet due to the extra single quotes around the sheet name. I believe that's what's caused the error.